# C - Library to deal with HTTPrequests

Tags: c, http

What's the best and most efficient library to deal with massive ammounts of HTTPrequests (cookies ,headers, everything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends in which language you want to use it. the libcurl is most commen e.g. in C:

http://curl.haxx.se

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for libcurl.Take a look at [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html) link.